# Meteor cordova push notification

Tags: cordova, meteor, push-notification

I'm trying to find an easy way to use push notification function with meteor and cordova together. Which plugin should I use? And a full example would be very helpfull. 
I found the package vom raix but don't know where to add and how use the `config.push.json` file?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example linked in the official documentation](https://github.com/elvismercado/meteor-raix-push-demo) using the `config.push.json` file.

This is an old question, but if you (just like me) got here looking for it recently, the `config.push.json` is deprecated. Now there's no need for it, a new API is defined in the `Push.Configure` function.

The [basic example](https://github.com/raix/push/blob/master/docs/BASIC.md) with the new API linked in the official README file.